# Is it possible to control the duration of the fade, or speed of motion in an Animation?

Tags: android, imageswitcher

I'm using ImageSwitcher and it works as described but the only two animations I see are fadeins/outs and slide ins from left and out to right.

I'm curious where (or if it's possible) I can set the animations to go to and come from different directions, and to control the speed of their entry exit, as well as the frequency of the fade.

Comment: Check this link out for more animation tutorials: http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343